# Can normalizr create an index on normalized data?

Tags: javascript, indexing, normalization

I use normalzr to normalize my data in my Redux store. However, I could not figure out how to create normalized indexes on the normalized data. Here is how I solved it without normalizr:

```
var postData = [
{ id: 101, pet: "dog", sleeps: "bed", likesme: "yes" },
{ id: 102, pet: "cat", sleeps: "porch", likesme: "no"  },
{ id: 103, pet: "fish", sleeps: "bowl", likesme: "yes"  },
{ id: 104, pet: "rock", sleeps: "porch", likesme: "yes"  }
];

const indexer = (objarr, idcol, indexcol) => {

  var retobj = {};     
  objarr.forEach((row)=>{

    var index = row[indexcol];
    if (retobj[index] == null)
      retobj[index] = [];

    retobj[index].push(row[idcol]);
  });

return(retobj);
};

var bySleeps = indexer(postData,"id","sleeps");
console.log(bySleeps);

var byLikesMe = indexer(postData,"id","likesme");
console.log(byLikesMe);
```

Produces:

```
{ bed: [ 101 ], porch: [ 102, 104 ], bowl: [ 103 ] }
{ yes: [ 101, 103, 104 ], no: [ 102 ] }
```

Example Usage:

```
var state.petsThatLikeMe = byLikesMe["yes"];
var state.petsThatDontLikeMe = byLikesMe["no"];
```

Comment: Im not familiar with normalizr. But i can imagine that id's are used to normalize data. In your example `bed` is not unique, so i think its hard to produce your current outcome just with normalizr.

Comment: I agree.  normalizr will create { '101':{ ...obj}, '102':{obj},...}. There are indexing tools on npm but want one that works with normalizr.

Comment: I might have something for you. Check my answer, hopefully it will help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, this will generate all possible keys with its values and the ids that belongs to those values.

If you will trigger this generate more often, it's a good idea to cache (memoize) the results, especially when the dataset becomes bigger.

`console.log(likesme);`

```
{
  "yes": [
    101,
    103,
    104
  ],
  "no": [
    102
  ]
}
```

`console.log(likesme.yes);`

```
[
  101,
  103,
  104
]
```

`console.log(sleeps.bed)`

```
[
  101
]
```

```js
var postData = [
  { id: 101, pet: "dog", sleeps: "bed", likesme: "yes" },
  { id: 102, pet: "cat", sleeps: "porch", likesme: "no" },
  { id: 103, pet: "fish", sleeps: "bowl", likesme: "yes" },
  { id: 104, pet: "rock", sleeps: "porch", likesme: "yes" }
];

function generate(data){
  return data.reduce((state, entry) => {
    Object.entries(entry).forEach(([subject, value]) => {
      if (subject in state) {
        value in state[subject] ?
          state[subject][value].push(entry.id) :
          state[subject][value] = [entry.id]
      } else {
        if (subject !== 'id') state[subject] = {[value]: [entry.id]};
      }
    });
    return state;
  }, {});
}

const { likesme, sleeps, pet } = generate(postData)

console.log(likesme);
console.log(likesme.yes);
console.log(sleeps.bed)
```